# Extracting NDVI by regions defined by certain column using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I am trying to extract NDVI values by regions of a certain polygon shapefile. I need, as output a graph (or a table) where the **regions** are defined by a certain column, called 'FID_incend'. I need exactly this column because those are unique values that I will use afterwards to process other maps.

My code is:

```
var incendis1987 = ee.FeatureCollection("users/oriolbaena/incendis1987_identityLitology_87929702_s_0p9HA_simplified");

Map.centerObject(incendis1987, 12);
Map.addLayer (incendis1987,{color: 'FF0000'})

var addNDVI = function (image){
  var ndvi= image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR")
    .filterBounds(incendis1987)
    .filterDate('1984-01-01', '1995-12-31')
    .map(addNDVI).select('NDVI');


var graph = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
imageCollection: dataset.select('NDVI'), 
regions: incendis1987,
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
scale: 30,
seriesProperty: FID_incend,
})
  .setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({title: 'NDVI Incendis1987 dates1984-1995', vAxis: {title:'NDVI'}, 
             lineWidth: 1,pointSize: 2,});
print(graph)
print ('I love JavaScript (L)')
```

As you can see, attibutes of my table include the column 'FID_incend':
[image]

The shp can be found here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/oriolbaena/incendis1987_identityLitology_87929702_s_0p9HA_simplified

Comment: Please share your incendis1987 feature collection.

Comment: I think this should work: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/oriolbaena/incendis1987_identityLitology_87929702_s_0p9HA_simplified Thanks Sean!

Comment: Did you set the "anyone can read" checkbox.  I get an error when trying to load it.

Comment: I think it should work if you try it again! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found your bug.  It is so small, it is easy to overlook.

your seriesProperty isn't in "quotes".
Modify your code in your `ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion()` function dictionary. so that the series property is in quotes.  It should work.

```
seriesProperty: "FID_incend",
```

[image: NDVI graph]

Comment: Sorry don't know how to add a picture in a comment! I posted another answer!